# Sublime Text and autoprefixer error browserslist caniuse-lite is outdated

Tags: autoprefixer

I'm using the *Sublime Text* application and the *Autoprefixer CSS* plugin.
A few days after running the plug-in, an error has appeared:

> *Autoprefixer: error browserslist caniuse-lite is outdated*

I updated the packages:

```
npm update -g browserslist caniuse-lite
```

Now they are current, but that doesn't change anything.
Can someone show me what the problem is?

Comment: I found a way - I entered the modules in Sublime and deleted the folder:
C: \ Users \ USER-NAME \ AppData \ Roaming \ Sublime Text 3 \ Packages \ Autoprefixer \ node_modules.
After the restart everything worked.

Comment: You should add your solution has an answer and not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Go to caniuse page on github

https://github.com/ben-eb/caniuse-lite

and download all files

and than replace only the folder name is data.

Other files is not necessery.